# Windows Azure and Dreamweaver

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver

Can I use Dreamweaver to build an HTML based site and then upload this site to the Azure platform via ftp, more specifically will Windows Azure recognise the default page for my website without explicitly having to reference it in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Azure PaaS (either Cloud Services or Web Sites), no. 
Azure IaaS, yes... with a bunch of initial setup.

You could spin up an Azure VM and host a plain HTML web site from within IIS there. You would need to configure the IIS web site (e.g. start page) and set up the FTP server when you first provision the server.

My gut feeling is that Windows Azure is not a very economical hosting model for a project of this kind though.